# Act as UPnP MediaServer & play streaming audio (mic) via UPnP MediaRender

Tags: java, audio-streaming, upnp, dlna

I have a little application which records audio eg. from the microphone.
Now I would like to provide that audio-stream via UPnP so a MediaRenderer can access and play it.

I'm already using CLING to discover the network for MediaRenders, but now I have no idea where to start with the streaming-part.

Can someone tell me where to start with UPnP as a beginner?

The final solution I would like to do is:

1. have my program which records audio eg. from microphone (done)
2. discover the network for MediaRenders (~done)
3. click on the MediaRenderer (act as a ControlPoint) and tell him "hey, play that stream"
   3.1 allow the MediaRenderer to also search for my program and choose it (partly done)
4. stream audio from program -> MediaRenderer

I don't need ready code or something like that. I'm just a bit struggling because I have no idea what to do, where to begin.

My open questions are at the moment:

I'm using JAVA and I'm sure I would find a way how to provide a PCM-audio-stream via HTTP.
But how to tell the MediaRender that he should now play that stream?

I'm a absolutely newbe here, any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

i've never used Cling but it looks like u need a UPNP Control Point, to search for Renderers and afterwards tell them what to play.
So this must be the class you need: http://4thline.org/projects/cling/core/apidocs/org/teleal/cling/controlpoint/ControlPoint.html

Comment: I'm experimenting with Cling meanwhile, so yes your answer is going in the right direction, thank you :)